# serving static files in spark java

Tags: spark-java

I have a complex hierarchy of static files to serve from the classpath, and the example at http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files does not suite my needs.

I tried to do this with a route, but it won't deliver a simple png. Is there a better way?

```
get("/assets/*", new Route() {
    @Override
    Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
        String path = request.pathInfo().replaceFirst("/assets/", "/somepathtoassets/");
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            response.type("image/png");
            response.status(200);
            Writer writer = response.raw().getWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
            writer.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it won't deliver a simple png"?

Comment: I've forgotten about this question or what the issue originally was, but I think it wouldn't deliver the png correctly, either as text or empty until I stopped using the IOUtils.copy method. or something like that. it has been a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question most helpful, but in a slightly different context. 
First off, the `IOUtils.copy` snippet fails because the `PrintWriter` instance returned by the `response.raw().getWriter()` call handles only character data. The second snippet works because the returned `response.raw().getOutputStream()` handles binary data.

To help others that might stumble across this who might have my problem: I was trying to run my Spark 2.1 application under Tomcat, not stand alone. When so configured, the `SparkFilter` class will, if you set a static file path, greedily serve everything under the static file locations, without giving your routes a chance to respond. And it will use the `getWriter()` call, hence corrupting any binary data that might be under the static file location.

So if you want to serve up static binary data, and you want to run your application using `SparkFilter` it looks like you have to write your own route handlers for the binary data, and then also ensure that the binary data lives outside of the static file paths, if you choose to use them.

I'm kind of sad that the logical semantics of running stand alone versus running under a Servlet engine are so different.

Comment: so using IOUtils.copy on the output streams should work?

Comment: IOUtils.copy expects a writer on the output stream, and as I understand it, Writers are only for character streams. So no, IOUtils.copy can't work with binary data. Thus the OutputStreamWriter in your example can be discarded...

Comment: I should've specified that I am using apache's IOUtils. http://tinyurl.com/m57kt3o ( at least, now I do, not sure if I was using that when I asked the question )

Comment: Oh: yes that should work. Apologies: I was so focused on Sparks code to try and understand what was going on in my case...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by not using IOUtils.copy, but doing the copy manually. with a byte buffer.

```
            InputStream inputStream = loadingClass.getResourceAsStream(path);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                response.type(getContentType(path));
                response.status(200);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                OutputStream os = response.raw().getOutputStream()
                OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                    os.write(buf, 0, count);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outWriter.close();

                return "";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
```